# Use Route param as array index in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In my `App` component, I fetch some data on component mount like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=10")
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
            posts: res.data
        });
    });
}
```

And inside the `render` funciton, I want to pass **only the specific post** as a prop based on the page ID:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route
        path="/posts/:postId"
        render={props => <Post {...props} post={this.state.posts[":postId"]} />}
    />
</BrowserRouter>
```

And I want to access the particular post from my `Post` component like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        id: this.props.match.params.postId,
        post: this.props.post
    });
}
```

But I cannot access the post data using `this.props.post`. Obviously the problematic line is where I try to set that post data:

```
render={props => <Post {...props} post={this.state.posts[":postId"]} />}
```

However I don't know how to pass the post data as a property to the `Post` component. I've just started learning React, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: React Router version ( ? )

Comment: "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0"

Comment: Did you mean to do `render={props => <Post {...props} post={this.state.posts[props.match.params.postId]}}`

Comment: [ https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/render-func ]
render: func 
This allows for convenient inline rendering and wrapping without the undesired remounting explained above.Instead of having a new React element created for you using the component prop, you can pass in a function to be called when the location matches. The render prop receives all the same route props as the component render prop.

Comment: @Li357 Unfortunately it didn't work. I'm just guessing but maybe that's because you can only use `props.match.params` on the recipient component?

Comment: @UtkuUfuk No, it's a part of the `props` object you are spreading to the component.

Comment: @UtkuUfuk you can do more, with the "withRouter" and the "connect" [https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter]